# Database is not accessible

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
conn = sqlite3.connect("~/Desktop/Personal/database_1.sqlite")
pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';", conn)
```

---

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-0d5f0352a16d> in <module>
  5 import sqlite3
  6 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  ----> 7 conn = sqlite3.connect("~/Desktop/Personal/database_1.sqlite")
  8 pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';", conn)

 OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

What could be the problem? It works on Kaggle when I import it but not when I try it on my desktop/personal files.

Comment: Did you try with absolute path like - "C:\\users\\guest\\desktop\....."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many programmatic interfaces won't do shell translations of paths. It will treat `~` as `~`.

You need to either give the full path to your file, or use the HOME environment variable.

```
import os
conn = sqlite3.connect("%s/Desktop/Personal/database_1.sqlite" % os.environ['HOME'])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! I had looked at other answers but they provided the answers above yet those did not work. Appreciate all the help, stay safe!